# setInterval and this.wait in casper.js

Tags: javascript, webkit, qtwebkit, phantomjs, casperjs

I need to make a loop of **3 times and 2 seconds in between each iteration**. I tried these 3 options:

**Option 1**

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: false,
    logLevel: 'debug'
});

casper.start("http://google.com");

casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
})

casper.thenEvaluate(function() {
    var x = 0;
    var intervalID = setInterval(function () {

       console.log("Using setInternal " + x);

       if (++x === 3) {
           window.clearInterval(intervalID);
       }
    }, 2000);

});

casper.run();
```

*Observation*: Nothing appeared because the script ended right away before the first `setInterval` being called.

**Option 2**

Replaced `thenEvaluate()` with `then()` below

```
for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
    this.wait(2000);
    this.echo('Using this.wait ' + i);
}
```

*Observation*: It outputs 3 times right away and then a long wait since `this.wait()` is async. This is not what I want because I want a delay in between.

**Option 3**
Replace the part in `then()` with this below. I was thinking about doing a recursive call to `waitFunc()` after each `wait()` being called.

```
var count = 0;
var waitFunc = function() {
    this.wait(2000, function() {
        if (count < 3) {
            casper.echo('Using this.wait ' + count);
            count++;
            waitFunc();
        }
    });

};
```

*Observation*: Nothing printed out on the screen.

So my question is: **How to make this.wait or setInterval works in a loop of 3 times like this case?**

Comment: I tried all 3 options and none worked

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a sample implementation to solve your problem:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var last, list = [0, 1, 2, 3];

casper.start("http://google.fr/", function() {
    this.echo('google');
});

casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
});

casper.thenEvaluate(function() {
    window.x = 0;
    var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
       console.log("Using setInternal " + window.x);
       if (++window.x === 3) {
           window.clearInterval(intervalID);
       }
    }, 500);
});

casper.each(list, function(self, i) {
    self.wait(500, function() {
        last = i;
        this.echo('Using this.wait ' + i);
    });
});

casper.waitFor(function() {
    return last === list[list.length - 1] && 3 === this.getGlobal('x');
}, function() {
    this.echo('All done.').exit();
});

casper.run(function() {});
```

Sample output:

```
$ casperjs test.js
google
remote message caught: Using setInternal 0
Using this.wait 0
remote message caught: Using setInternal 1
Using this.wait 1
remote message caught: Using setInternal 2
Using this.wait 2
Using this.wait 3
All done.
$
```

Comment: It works. But can you explain the use of casper.each vs. for loop? Why self.wait() works in this case. Using for loop will execute all this.echo() then the long wait.

Comment: It's because of how javascript scoping works. A standard `for` loop will always have the latest value of `i` set, that's why you generally have to use an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) (`Casper.each` wraps the loop within an IIFE).

Comment: Ah, based on the link, this works too: casper.then(function() {
 for (i=0; i<=3; i++) {
  this.wait(2000, (function(j) {
   return function() {
    this.echo('Test ' + j);
   };
  })(i));
 }
});

Comment: Yeah sure, as I said `Casper.each()` just uses an IIFE internally :)